# Why does the color of my image change when it's reviewed on a mobile device?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, cmyk, mobile, color-spaces

I exported my vector CMYK file from Illustrator as an RGB image. On my customer's mobile, the colors change and he can not review the work to approve it.

What can I do to display the correct colors?

Comment: Your question is too broad. How did you export the image, and in which format?  Did you try Save For Web, or are you using Export? Have you tried saving as a jpeg, using sRGB as the colour profile?

Comment: Hello Ahmad. Welcome to GD.SE. Please give us a bit more information, like a screenshot of your file and possibly how it shows with the incorrect colours; your colour settings, and the things Billy Kerr asks about. Without this data, it is almost impossible to tell you what is wrong and how to solve it. Thanks. Please have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] to better understand this site and how the Stack Exchange model works.

Comment: thanks for your responses
my file always CMYK  . and yes i'm using normal export as   choose jpeg and CHANGE color mode  to  RGB..

Comment: @AhmadFarghaly unfortunately mobile devices are really bad at color reproduction.

Comment: What are the correct colours? Do you have a calibrated CMYK screen? (I want one too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Educate your customer.

If they are hiring you to do some print work (evidenced by the CMYK setting), they should never review that work just casually on a phone. Ask them to take the time for the review and urge them to look at your comps on a computer.

As joojaa says in the comments, colour reproduction on a mobile device can be absolutely horrible, and is dependent upon a multitude of uncontrollable factors like mobile OS, viewing software, screen settings and ambient light.

Honestly, if a customer would review my print comps on a mobile, I'd be very insulted at how casually they take my hard work.